# Linux: Mouse cursor continuous rightward movement, even with mouse disconnected

Tags: debian, xfce, mouse, cursor

Mouse cursor randomly starts slowly and continuously moving rightwards, even after disconnecting my mouse it still continues rightwards. I switched user, then switched back to my original user and its fixed now but what might have caused this? Have had this happen to me ~5 times now. Really worried.

System: desktop PC
OS and DE: Debian 11, XFCE4

Comment: Maybe an other pointer system connected somehow does this rather than the mouse? `xinput list` will list such devices.

Comment: @A.B, I do have a controller connected to my PC, and it does control my cursor as well so it could be that. Though I wonder why it stops happening when I switch users. The only way to know if its the controller or not would be to wait for it to happen again I guess. Or is it impossible for some software error to be the cause?

Comment: Wait for it to happen again and disable it: `xinput disable ID`. If it stops happening you got the culprit. Software error could (including something requiring recalibration). Softwares can also move mouse (eg: remote access using vnc etc.) probably through `Virtual core XTEST pointer` or similar. Sorry I'm not writing any answer because the possibilities are too wide.